Significance of the Temple in the Days of the Messiah
Contemplating the 9th of Av aspirations, I understand that the main reason for our yearning for the Days of the Messiah is to solve the inherent condition of human suffering: poverty, sickness, wars, and more.
The Jewish tradition holds the reestablishment of the Temple to be an integral part of the Days of the Messiah incl./excl. animal sacrifices and the rest of the Templaic works.
IIRC, according to Maimonides (and the late Hassidic tradition), a transcendent and omnipresent God does not need a place to dwell, and surely does not "enjoy" the sacrifices or Templaic works. And, I suppose, no present-day rabbi would oppose. Many also agree with the Gemmorah (Niddah.61b) that in the perfect world, there would be no Mitzvos to observe (incl. the Temple) and no possibility for sin.
In the Messianic utopia, what is the role and significance of the third Temple? I.e. why is the Temple important after the world is perfect?

", I understand that the main reason for our yearning for the Days of the Messiah is to solve the inherent condition of human suffering: poverty, sickness, wars, and more" why is that your understanding?

In the Rambam's model, the Messianic days will not be fundamentally different from current times. Whatever need there was for the Temple in the past will be equally applicable in the future. That said, there's no consensus on either point, and you're misrepresenting the Hasidic view.

Please provide some sources for the hasidic sources. Also, I am sure you know how the Yaavetz felt about the rambam's explanation the korbanos

https://dafaleph.com/home/2017/2/1/sanctuary-and-sacrifice-rambams-view-of-korbanot

@Yoreinu Did you read my comment that got deleted? What I wrote in the body is irrelevant to the question, I only provided "soft" bases for the Temple in the Messianic days being somewhat unnecessary.

Rambam on mashiach (Hil. Melachim 11) https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.11.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en "the Messianic king will arise and renew the Davidic dynasty, restoring it to its initial sovereignty. He will build the Temple and gather the dispersed of Israel. Then, in his days, the observance of all the statutes will return to their previous state. We will offer sacrifices, observe the Sabbatical and Jubilee years according to all their particulars as described by the Torah." He didn't list all mitzvos we'd do then, but he specifically mentions sacrifices - first.

So if you're quoting the Rambam it should be noted that he doesn't agree with you at all.

@MichoelR You are absolutely right. It's not the first time Rambam contradicts himself. Given his arguments that we can not know how things will unfold and that animal sacrifices were a concession to the prevalent cultural practices of the time, rather than an inherent or ideal form of worship, I assume it is plausible that he mentioned the sacrifices in the Messianic days as a metaphor of "business as usual".

"contradicts himself". Maybe consider the possibility that you should try to find a consistent interpretation of both. I don't think that's impossible or even that hard.

When someone is in love, they feel a need to give. For example, a husband could buy his wife flowers that she looks at for a few minutes while putting them in a vase and a couple of glances at Shabbos dinner, but basically ignores. The flowers aren't needed. The gesture of giving is.
The fact that we don't feel this way about G-d says something about what Galus has done to our relationship.
(I took this idea, but added the metaphor, from the Narbonni's commentary on Moreh Nevuchuim. It's from his answer to the Ramban's and others' fundamental problem with the Rambam's explanation of the purpose of Qorbanos.)
We are going to need a building, and need qorbanos.
Aside from the qorbanos and tefillah aspect, the Beis haMiqdash was also a the seat of justice and legislation, since the Sanhedrin meets there. And both the Kohanim and Sanhedrin teach Torah.
So, the Beis haMiqdash will again be the central place for developing the Emunah and Bitachon to have the backbone and security to share our resources with others. It will be a place of where we learn and internalize Torah about things like when Chessed helps, and when it would just enable and exacerbate problems -- the whole reason why we need financial and other interpersonal dinim, rather than rely on our natural sense of Good.

It seems that you are trying to follow the opinion of Ramban that mitzvos were conceived prior to Creation and have eternal meaning. Therefore, the Rashi's point of the Mishkan/Temple as an atonement for the sin of the Golden Calf is secondary to the one conceived at Creation. What you are trying to do is to spell this meaning. However, could you bring sources and connect? What will be the purpose of the building? What will be the purpose of korbanos?

Thank you, you started well and suddenly jumped to "We are going to need a building, and need sacrifices.". Why? Didn't the sages render prayers comparable to sacrifices? Didn't they establish God's omnipresence and his presence at every shul and house? You may continue to recite prayers and learn the Torah as a sign of your love of God.

I don't think the sages did that though. They set up prayer about the same time sacrifices resuned with the Second Beis haMiqdash. And then they said that they are a solid second best for when actual sacrifices aren't an option. As for why... I said why: because a person really feels like they are in a relationship, they naturally feel a need for a gesture of giving. Which  prayer isn't.

@ydj I said what I thought the purpose was. As for a source, I vaguely cited the Narbonni's commentary on the Moreh Nevuchim. It's on 3:32. And he is defending the Rambam against the Ramban!

Even if it were true that all mitzvot are nullified, one can still use a Temple to worship God without reward/command.
Pirkei Avot 1:3
Antigonos of Sokho received [the Tradition] from Shimon HaTzadik (the Righteous). He would say, "Do not be as servants who serve their master in order to receive reward; rather, be as servants who serve their master not in order to receive reward; and may the fear of Heaven be upon you."

This was not the question. it was about Temple's role in the Messianic days.

It will do the exact same things it did before.

Why? If we go back to אדם הראשון לפני החטא for example, there was no [need for] temple in Eden. If we "fulfill" some kind of a Tikkun, and God doesn't need it, we don't need it either.

If the goal is to return to living naked in a forest, one can't justify learning not currently useful Gemara about korbanos.
